# Order results by column dynamically depending on where a match was found

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm selecting data from a table where one of 3 columns matches a given search string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CARS
WHERE MODEL LIKE searchString
OR MANUFACTURER LIKE searchString
OR DESCRIPTION LIKE searchString
```

But I need to order the results depending on where the match was found, based on a column weighting. I.e. if the match was found in the MODEL column then the row should appear higher in the results than if the match was found in the MANUFACTURER column. With the weighting being 1-MODEL 2-MANUFACTURER 3-DESCRIPTION.

All help hugely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Oracle's Full Text Search (FTS) functionaltiy--Oracle Text-- would be both faster and provide a rank score based on it's algorithm...

```
SELECT c.*,
            CASE 
                WHEN c.model LIKE searchstring THEN 1
                WHEN c.manufacturer LIKE searchstring THEN 2
                WHEN c.description LIKE searchstring THEN 3
            END AS match_rank
    FROM CARS c
  WHERE c.model LIKE searchstring
        OR c.manufacturer LIKE searchstring
        OR c.description LIKE searchstring
ORDER BY match_rank
```

But you don't mention how to handle the ranking if two more more columns match....

Comment: the ranking should stop once a match has been found. Is this as simple as adding an 'END' to the end of each 'WHEN' statement?

Comment: Just realised that once a condition is found to be true, the case statement will return the result and not evaluate the conditions any further. So this is perfect, cheers!

Comment: good solution, but check performance on large tables.. if returning everything then shouldn't make much of a difference, just the cost of the sort. But if returning a TOP(x) subset then the whole table needs to be sorted by the match first. Check the execution plan fits your requirement..